# How to get grand total of all input values in javascript if dynamically entered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, input

I'm looking to acquire a grand total of all product input field values that are dynamically generated when a user clicks on either the plus or minus button which, for that, adds the total price for each product.

Any help is greatly appreciated. This is what I have so far:

JS

```
$(function() {
  $('.service_product-item').each(function() {
    var thisEl = $(this),
      btnPlus = thisEl.find('.service_btn-plus'),
      btnMinus = thisEl.find('.service_btn-minus'),
      fieldQtt = thisEl.find('input[name="service-qt1"],input[name="service-qt2"]'),
      itemPriceEl = thisEl.find('.service_item-price'),
      price = itemPriceEl.data('price');
    // Add Products & Products Price
    btnPlus.on('click', function() {
      qttValue = parseInt(fieldQtt.val());
      fieldQtt.val(qttValue + 1);
      itemPriceEl.html('$' + (qttValue + 1) * price);
    });
    // Subtract Products & Products Price
    btnMinus.on('click', function() {
      qttValue = parseInt(fieldQtt.val()) - 1;
      var newQTT = (qttValue <= 0) ? 0 : qttValue;
      fieldQtt.val(newQTT);
      itemPriceEl.html('$' + newQTT * price);
    });
  });
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="service_products_and_services_wrapper">
  <div class="service_product-items">
    <div class="service_product-item">
      <div class="service_item-wrap">
        <img src="http://www.kinyu-z.net/data/wallpapers/27/796765.png" alt="QT1" title="" />
        <div class="service_wrap-qtt">
          <div class="service_wrap-qtt-field-qtt">
            <input class="service_field-qtt" name="service-qt1" value="0" readonly="" />
          </div>
          <div class="service_wrap-qtt-minus-plus">
            <div class="service_btn-cart-qtt service_btn-plus">+</div>
            <div class="service_btn-cart-qtt service_btn-minus">-</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="service_item-info">
        <div class="service_item-title">QT1<br>
          <span style="font-size: .7em; text-transform: none;">($5 per item)</span>
        </div>
        <div class="service_item-price" data-price="5">$0</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="service_product-item">
      <div class="service_item-wrap">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRIuVn6ZXHwQiFC0IlB1N_CxbXo6-5x1A4yqspYsxUUb0Xjmu8L" alt="QT2" title="" />
        <div class="service_wrap-qtt">
          <div class="service_wrap-qtt-field-qtt">
            <input class="service_field-qtt" name="service-qt2" value="0" readonly="" />
          </div>
          <div class="service_wrap-qtt-minus-plus">
            <div class="service_btn-cart-qtt service_btn-plus">+</div>
            <div class="service_btn-cart-qtt service_btn-minus">-</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="service_item-info">
        <div class="service_item-title">QT2<br>
          <span style="font-size: .7em; text-transform: none;">($10 per item)</span>
        </div>
        <div class="service_item-price" data-price="10">$0</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p style="margin-top: 40px;">Grand Total: $0</p>
</div>
```

and here is a [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Lyxceu3s/18/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some issues with the problem statement. Main one is that you don't really have any model defined for your application and your html acts as a data model as well, and important data is scoped to the event handlers. Also it is not clear what is the initial state of that application. So I just modify your code a bit.

One simple approach just to show how it could be done is following:

- have a global total
- with each minus and plus update the value accordingly

https://jsfiddle.net/Lyxceu3s/43/

```
var total = 0;
$(function() {
  $('.service_product-item').each(function() {
    var thisEl = $(this),
      btnPlus = thisEl.find('.service_btn-plus'),
      btnMinus = thisEl.find('.service_btn-minus'),
      fieldQtt = thisEl.find('input[name="service-qt1"],input[name="service-qt2"]'),
      itemPriceEl = thisEl.find('.service_item-price'),
      price = itemPriceEl.data('price');
    // Add Products & Products Price
    btnPlus.on('click', function() {
      qttValue = parseInt(fieldQtt.val());
      fieldQtt.val(qttValue + 1);
      total = total + price;
      itemPriceEl.html('$' + (qttValue + 1) * price);
      $('#idGT').html(total);
    });
    // Subtract Products & Products Price
    btnMinus.on('click', function() {
      qttValue = parseInt(fieldQtt.val()) - 1;
      if(qttValue >= 0){
         total = total - price;
      }
      var newQTT = (qttValue <= 0) ? 0 : qttValue;
      fieldQtt.val(newQTT);
      itemPriceEl.html('$' + newQTT * price);
      $('#idGT').html(total);
    });
  });
});
```

And that would also require a little modification to your html:

```
<p style="margin-top: 40px;">Grand Total: $<span id="idGT">0</span></p>
```

Note: that in case of a minus, you have to check that quantity is above or 0 before you conditionally reset it to 0.

As a general note, you might want to separate your models from your views. Check the following SO thread for a digest: ["Hello World" in MVC Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8497833/hello-world-in-mvc-pattern)

Answer (score 0):

Updated the fiddle. Made few changes to it
Please take a look at it and let me know if thats what you are looking for.

https://jsfiddle.net/Lyxceu3s/35/

```
      var firstTotal =  $('input[name="service-qt2"]').val() * 10 ; 
      var secondTotal = $('input[name="service-qt1"]').val() * 5;
      $('#grandTotal').html(firstTotal + secondTotal)
```

Comment: G_S, even though this works just as good, I went with Vladimir's answer as his is more of a global approach where I wouldn't need to add a var for each input name if I add more products.  Thanks for showing me an alternate way of doing this though!  Much appreciated!

Comment: Yes. This is just with what you currently have. I didnt do much changes to your existing structure. Even I feel Vladimir's is more of a global approach.